# HTML validation for the keyboard

Tags: android, html

I use  for zip code field. When I test in Android browser, virtual keyboard appear special characters, example: N (what's this?), ".", "/", "*", ... and numeric key for telephone. When I do some validate in client-side, it have errors. So, I want to ignore or disable this special characters, only show numeric keys. I also try attribute pattern="[0-9]*" but I don't work. What should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type="number"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```